# Resizing an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this [webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) , after capturing the image(default is 320x240) i want to re size the image to 100x100 (for profile picture capturing). 
i tried using scaling but it is cropping the image not resizing the image.

Comment: 320x240 isn't very big. Upload it to your server and resize there.

Comment: Since 240x320 and 100x100 are different shapes, you cannot proportionally scale a 240x320 to 100x100.  You can force it to be 100x100, but then it will be squished in one dimension and square or round things will no longer have their original shape.  Or, you can clip the long edge and scale it down to 100x100 to display only a square section of the image.  Which do you want to do?

Comment: i have space constraint at the client side to display and if i resize at the  server side again have to load from there.

Comment: even if the image quality gone no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the img tag itself to re-size the image

```
<img src='./imagename.jpg' style="display: inline; width: 100px; height: 100px">
```

Is it what u want? You can do it java script also

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for resizing the image.

here, 'this' represents image.
var maxWidth = 320; // Max width for the image
        var maxHeight = 240;    // Max height for the image
        var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

```
    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if(width > maxWidth){
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
        $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if(height > maxHeight){
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
        $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }
```